# Java communicating with a webservice

Tags: java, php, web-services, sockets

I need to write an application in java which communicates with a web server.
I know how to do that, using PHP, but I'm afraid it won't cut it in this one.

Here's my situation.
I have multiple clients, when one of them sends a specific message to the server (so far, no problem on PHP), I want it to send a certain message to all other connected clients.
The problem is, I could hardly find any information regarding server socket in PHP, which led me to believe this isn't the proper way of achieving that. I'm using a paid hosting (x10premium) to host my servers so far, so I was thinking of doing it with this one, however, I'm not sure it's even possible with PHP.
At the moment I'm having each of the clients periodically check with the server if he received a message from any of the other clients, but I don't like this solution...
I hope someone could point me to the right direction. I don't know too much about Ruby and other languages which are used to do stuff like that, But if necessary, I would gladly learn it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, the server (currently the PHP) would also communicate with a MySQL table. If it matters.

Comment: PHP is not a real-time scripting language .... secondly, who is the client here? PHP or Java

Comment: So what is your question? How to do this in Java? If it is possible in Java? If there is a way to do it in PHP?

Comment: This is certainly possible in Java (and not too difficult from my point of view), but without more specifics, it's difficult to tell what you want to know beyond that.

Comment: Java is the client. I'm now looking into python, as @Veseliq offered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of PHP socket server/client:
http://tech.navarr.me/2010/07/how-to-create-a-socket-server-in-php.html

You could do it just like with JAVA, but remember that PHP does not support multithreading or multiprocessing so if 10 clients connect at once to your server, you will process them one by one, so eventually 1 will have to wait for the other 9 to finish - everything, database and connection overhead.

If you do it with JAVA or Python for example, you could handle each request in separate thread so that DB & Network communication overhead is handled simultaneosly.

Python has build in socket server components and nice and easy to use mysql component, that would make it a breez to achieve this, without even having to understand threading at all.

For the python socket server see here:

http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html

Basically you just define a function that will be executed for each new client connection and tell the server to `serve_forever()` - until it dies, it will do what you want.

Comment: I'm having trouble creating sockets in my shared host (x10hosting premium). they allow me to run python, but it fails to create the socket.

Comment: That's not surprising - no host would allow you to create sockets or open ports. Get a VPS.